# Reset View of webpage JSF

Tags: jsf, view, reset

Is there a way to reset the view of a page in JSF?
  I have a page to upload files and it keeps filling a table with the files the user wants to submit, once the user clicks on submit I want the page to be in the initial state as if it was the first time the user visited it.

Hope I explain myself correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching and thinking a bit, I think I got it.
Just in the `action` attribute of the `submit` button redirect the page to the same page, this will cause to create a new view of the same page.